# can i use mail() for this code "<input type='text' name='current_user_first_name' value='<?php echo $current_user_firstname; ?>'>

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I want to insert the following code in the message part of a php mail().

```
"<input type='text' id='current_user_first_name' 
name='current_user_first_name' value='<?php echo 
$current_user_firstname; ?>'>"
```

\ The full message will look like the following.

```
    $to="$managers_email";
    $subject="REQUEST FOR APPROVAL";
    $message=
    "<html>
    <head>
    <title>REQUEST FOR TIME SHEET APPROVAL</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type='text' id='current_user_first_name' 
    name='current_user_first_name' value='<?php echo 
    $current_user_firstname; ?>'>

   <input type='submit' value='APPROVED' 
   formaction='http://telecomsolutions.com/approved.php'>
   <input type='submit' value='DRAFT REJECT'>

    <textarea name='reject_reason' placeholder='Enter reject 
    reason' 
    id='reject_reason' rows='15' cols='30'>

    <input type='submit' value='REJECT' 
    formaction='http://telecomsolutions.com/reject.php'>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>";
    $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0" ."\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
    $headers.='from:<$current_user_email>'."\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    echo "Your request submitted successfully"      
    ?>
```

Each time a client submits a request for approval the details of the client will be fetched from the database, used in place of the variables in the html code and sent to the Manager for approval.

Please can this work and if not,any other way to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried it? If yes then what result you are getting?

Comment: Yes i've tried it. the PHP code in the input field is not executing. it comes out just that way in the email message

Comment: `$headers.='from:<$current_user_email>'."\r\n";` needs to be `$headers.="from:<$current_user_email>"."\r\n";` or else the variable won't be interpolated (double quotes behave differently to single quotes in PHP (unless the config is changed).

Comment: P.S. a lot of mail clients won't allow you to have forms inside an email. There's a very high chance this simply won't work. You're going to need to have hyperlinks instead, which link to e.g. `http://telecomsolutions.com/approved.php?id=123` where ID denotes the ID of the approval request. It would also make sense to have some security on the PHP scripts so that people can't just approve and deny other timesheets based on guessing the ID.

Comment: (Currently, your mail seems to have no way at all of determining which timesheet request is being approved by clicking on the links, or who is doing the approval. Instead of simple IDs you could also use GUIDs to obfuscate the request ID and make it hard to guess. Also it seems strange you have the first name and last name in textboxes - why would the approver be able to edit the name of the person requesting approval? Or is it the approver's name? They should have to log in to identify themselves, not just simply type a name. I don't think you have thought this through fully.)

Comment: Hi ADyson, i'm using session id  to identify each current user and tracking their request for approval. They will definitely log in to request for approval. Is there any alternative to sending firstname and lastname in text boxes. The names are actually tied to the form so that  on approval the right section of the approval table will be updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $variable = "John Doe";
  $message = "Hi " . $variable . " , How are you?";
```

The above will result in
`Hi John Dow , How are you?`

You **won't** do like this

```
  $variable = "John Doe";
  $message = "Hi <?php echo  $variable ?> , How are you?";
```

The first mistake you are doing is using `<?php` again inside your PHP file.
Then the second mistake is to use `echo` inside your above mentioned `<php`

Correct `$message` will be

```
$message=
          "<html>
              <head>
                <title>REQUEST FOR TIME SHEET APPROVAL</title>
                <style>
                </style>
              </head>
              <body>
                <form>
                  <input type='text' id='current_user_first_name' name='current_user_first_name' value='" .   $current_user_firstname . "'>

                  <input type='submit' value='APPROVED'  formaction='http://telecomsolutions.com/approved.php'>
                  <input type='submit' value='DRAFT REJECT'>
                  <textarea name='reject_reason' placeholder='Enter reject reason' id='reject_reason' rows='15' cols='30'>
                  <input type='submit' value='REJECT' formaction='http://telecomsolutions.com/reject.php'>
                </form>
              </body>
          </html>";
```

The above one still looks complex and difficult to manage.

You can use concatenation (`.`)

```
$message="<html>"
          .    "<head>"
          .      "<title>REQUEST FOR TIME SHEET APPROVAL</title>"
          .      "<style>"
          .      "</style>"
          .    "</head>"
          .    "<body>"
          .      "<form>"
          .        "<input type='text' id='current_user_first_name' 
                     name='current_user_first_name' 
                     value='" .   $current_user_firstname . "'>"

          .        "<input type='submit' value='APPROVED'  formaction='http://telecomsolutions.com/approved.php'>"
          .        "<input type='submit' value='DRAFT REJECT'>"
          .        "<textarea name='reject_reason' placeholder='Enter reject reason' id='reject_reason' rows='15' cols='30'>"
          .        "<input type='submit' value='REJECT' formaction='http://telecomsolutions.com/reject.php'>"
          .      "</form>"
          .    "</body>"
          . "</html>";
```

Comment: Personally I think the concatenation style is more verbose and less readable, but that's just opinion. You're correct about the first part (echoing within an existing string)

Comment: The concatenation is just an option for the person [Joba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14966064/joba) to explore different ways to use multiple concatenations of string to work. Perhaps it is true some find it quite difficult to read.

Comment: Many thanks "Not A Bot" and ADyson. i will implement the steps and possibly post the result for you to see. Thanks.